# Shortest path change in weighted graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

In a weighted graph does the shortest path between two vertices change if we add to all the weights the same positive number?

Comment: the title and body seem to be different.

Comment: Also, are the weights non-negative?

Answer (score 1):

If the weights are non-negative then the answer is no:

The lightest path is going to consist of only one edge, the lightest edge in the graph, it should be clear this edge will still be the lightest after adding a constant to each edge's weight.

---

If the weights can be negative then things change:
[image]

In this graph the lightest path is $A,B,C$ with weight $-2$. Which is the lightest path if we add $2$ to each edge?

---

Assuming the question asks about the shortest path between two fixed vertices:

[image]

The lightest path from $A$ to $B$ is $A,C,B$ and has weight $2$. Which is the lightest path after adding $2$ to each edge?

Comment: I suppose the question is about the shortest path between two fixed vertices.

Comment: Oh, I see. I'll change it to that then.

Comment: The answer proposed in not very clear. Yes, the shortest path may change, as shown in the second example (even if the weights are positive).